# upload video on twitter with share kit or oauth

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, sharekit

I need to add the uploading video concept on twitter through my app. I have tried every possible solution i.e. oath, share kit but didn't get any success. I am able to post image with oauth as well as share kit. But when I tried share kit for uploading the video it make the incomplete yfrog link i.e. frog.com  but when I click on the link there is nothing in that. Can anybody tell me that what I am doing wrong in this. Please help me out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is interesting - I "sometimes" experience the same. Video is uploaded OK, but the response contains general link only. Sometimes the response is OK. Wonder if this has to do something with limits on yfrog, or some setting with yfrog. I am confident that the code is OK. Unfortunately we can not upload video to Twitter directly.v If you have any news on this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you cant upload video to twitter (you can post URL of video ). twitter not allow to post video it is possible for vine app. only (because of vine app developed by twitter) .

Comment: How to make the link of video with vine api

Comment: there is no api available on net i search many times but i did't got that. :( so you have  to share link of video only ;)

Comment: how to make the link If I fetch the video from gallery